# Why can I save my Dogecoin on Binance Smart Chain (BSC)?

Tags: blockchain, metamask, bsc

I thought Dogecoin was the token of a totally different blockchain network which isn't Ethereum-compatible? When I tried to google "**dogecoin metamask**" looking for a way to use metamask as the wallet for dogecoin, [every resource](https://svenkuehn.medium.com/adding-dogecoin-token-to-metamask-fdfc0ed59ec) points to adding **BSC** as a custom network and then I can send my dogecoin to the **BSC** network.

Why? Why is it possible to send the token to a totally different block chain network?

Wouldn't it be duplicates or simply lost or not trusted? Doesn't quite make sense to me.

According to [metamask doc](https://community.metamask.io/t/how-to-add-custom-networks-to-metamask-like-binance-and-polygon-matic/3634), Dogecoin cannot be added to MetaMask:

> Please note that neither Bitcoin, Dogecoin or Cardano are NOT Etheruem compatible, so they cannot be added to MetaMask and require
> their own wallet.

So I'm quite confused here. Is it possible to add dogecoin to metamask or not?

If yes, is it safe at all?

Comment: Read the [What Are Wrapped Tokens](https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/what-are-wrapped-tokens) article on the Binance Academy website.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Thanks! As I read and understand it, wrapped token requires a custodian and is thus centralized? So a dogecoin on BSC is as safe as the custodian is trustworthy, correct? A wrapped dogecoin is NOT a dogecoin in the native network, right?

Comment: "yes" - to all questions.

Comment: Note though that a wrapped DOGE has the same dollar value as a native DOGE. It's just the technology underlying the two tokens that is different.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to add DOGECOIN to metamask.
You are trying to make to add a Binance Peg Dogecoin (this [token](https://www.coingecko.com/it/monete/binance-peg-dogecoin)).
This token (like: BTCB) are pegged token that means are ancored with the value of a 'real' coin.
In case of BTC, BTCB is ancored at the price of bitcoin.
The same argument is for Dogecoin in this case.